# Can't reference keys in returning JSON

Tags: jquery

I'm returning some JSON from the web server, but I am unable to reference any of the keys.

```
{"voteid":110.0,"message":"Your request was processed.","success":true}
```

Alerting response.message/voteid alerts `undefined`

```
alert(response.voteid);
```

Alerting the full string works fine: `alert(response);` but that's no good since I want to reference the keys individually. My end goal is to get the voteid key from the JSON and append it to a anchor, which also does not work--with a full string or just a key:

```
success: function(response) { $(".fav").data("voteid", response.voteid) }
<a class="fav" data-voteid="">
```

On a side note, I don't know why there's a 0 at the end of the voteid. I'm returning the number as a string!

**EDIT:** Fixed by setting the dataType to JSON, however, the data will not append to the anchor's data-voteid attribute.

**EDIT** Got it to append the id by using .attr instead of .data -- many thanks everyone!

Comment: Just so it's said, it feels wrong to have floating-point fields called "id".

Comment: cHao, I don't know why that's happening though. I'm returning a string. I don't know where this is coming from!

Comment: @cHao: JavaScript doesn't have integers. Neither does JSON. `110.0` seems an odd choice, though. :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: No, but i'm willing to bet the server-side language does.

Comment: @cHao: Me too. :-) As I said, the `.0` on the end of that does look...odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've excluded some key parts of your code, but I'm guessing you haven't set `dataType:'json'` for your request.

Or you could manually call `$.parseJSON`:

```
success: function(response) { 
    var parsed = $.parseJSON( response );
    $("fav").data("voteid", parsed.voteid);
}
```

Remember, JSON *is* text.

Comment: It was 'script' changing to 'json' fixed it, duhh.... but it still will not append to the data-voteid="" in the anchor!

Comment: @mel, @patrick dw: Better still would be leaving `dataType` off entirely and having the server return the correct content type.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting back your JSON as a string when you want it back as an object. Try the following:

> var responseObject = eval(response);
>
> alert(responseObject.voteId)

and then google for why eval is not a good idea and how to work around that.

Comment: `eval` should almost never be used, including 'parsing' JSON. It's easy, but very dangerous.

Comment: It was 'script' instead of 'json' that broke it :/ -- but the value will not append to the acnhor's data-voteid attribute!

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the datatype as json in your ajax call? Its probably returning the JSON as a string which won't allow you to access the keys. If you specify JSON jquery will convert the string into an object